# API For Google PageSpeed Insight

Tags: api, pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

I just setup Google PageSpeed Insight into my Google Webmaster but whenever I am trying to do PageSpeed Test this error occurs "The referrer https://www.googleapis.com/ does not match the referrer restrictions configured on your API key. Please use the API Console to update your key restrictions."

I already created API for my URL and Created Restriction of HTTPS Referrers and submitted my Website in it but still not working.

Any solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

You have set your restrictions incorrectly, the error message points you directly to the problem.

Remove all restrictions and try again, then slowly add restrictions until you reach the problem.

If you have restricted `Accept requests from these HTTP referrers (web sites) (Optional)` then bear in mind you have to verify your site first for some APIs to function correctly.